# How to set the width of Underline in attributed text

Tags: ios6, nsattributedstring, underline

I am using UITextView and adding attributed text to it. I want to set underline to the text according to the font size, but i was only able to set the size 1. If any one have any idea regarding this please tell.

The code i am using is:-

```
NSDictionary* dict = nil;
dict = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],
         NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor],
          NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @1
               };
TextView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"String to be underline" attributes:dict];
```